# How to add "click" or "change" event on product thumbnail images in frontend?

Tags: magento2, javascript, thumbnail, fotorama

I am trying a "click" or "change" event on fotorama thumbnail images. While clicking the thumbnail images I need to fire a "click" or "change" event.
I have read the below documents but am unable to find a proper solution. Suggest me if anyone has an idea on this.

Devdocs link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_gallery.html#gallery_seek

[image]

Comment: are you searching for the phtml file?

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya I am not looking for phtml file. I need a click or change event while changing the fotorama thumbnail images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There are three ways to change the image `Nav Frame image click`, `Nav prev/next arrow click` and `Slide the image`.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
2. jQuery event dispatched on **dispatch()** method on 5192 line from `{Magento2 root directory}/lib/web/jquery.js`. In that method, at line 5231 the handler is applied for the **matched.element** in which whole gallery div is handled.
   [image]
   [image]
3. In code flow handler takes to `{Magento2 root directory}/lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js` in which at line 2765 `navUpdate()` or at line 5417 `updateFotoramaState()` method will be apt for the requirement.
4. Using the file `fotorama.js` in theme or mapping in `requirejs-config.js`, you can add the additional logic in that.

Answer (score 3):

This is also one of the answers for achieving click events on thumbnail images without modifying the `fotorama.js` file which suits my requirement.

We can directly add the click event for the nav frame thumbnail image click.

```
$(document).on('click', '.fotorama__nav__frame', function () {
   console.log(this);
});
```

But by using this event we cannot track nav updates in the thumbnail images such as *prev/next arrow click* and *slide the image*.

---