# is mixin for library file's method possible?

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, mixins, lib

1. I was solving one of the issues from the other [stack exchange question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344140/how-to-add-click-or-change-event-on-product-thumbnail-images-in-frontend).
2. The fotorama library file which is located in `lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js` has one method `navUpdate(){...}` at 2765 line. I want to override the function with additional logic.
3. I can achieve that in two ways. One is taking the whole file to the theme `app/design/frontend/{vendor_name}/{theme_name}/web/fotorama` or on the second choice can write the mapping for the whole file using `requirejs-config.js`.
4. In an above-mentioned way, I have to copy and rewrite the whole file (around 3800+ lines) again just to add few lines in that which seems not right. I tried to achieve it via mixin but it doesn't seem to be possible.

**Question:** Is mixin possible to override the `navUpdate(){...}` method from `lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js`? or is there any other approach in which not to rewrite the whole file again to avoid boilerplate?